# Where to post - Hardware assembly

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask Questions where I need help in assembling hardware, and recommendations for what to buy? My question is -

> Hi everyone,
>
> I was just wondering if it is possible to make a barebones laptop from scratch??
>   I don't want to buy a barebones, since I want to build the chassis myself, so how do I fix the other components (like motherboard, LCD, keyboard & mouse
>   )? I know how to fix the other components once I have my Customized *Bareones laptop* ready. Some components I Will be using are -
>
> `Processor - Intel I3
>   Ram - Kingston Technology HyperX Impact 8GB`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem here is that its really too broad. Quite literally, with custom hardware, you do what you need to - ranging from [3d printing](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=3d%20printed%20laptop&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=J1-jWq3iEMLWvAT16bhg) to various laser cut cases - as done with the [novena](https://hackaday.com/tag/novena/).

You need to consider power (and that's dependant on the platform), interfaces (you can easily get a controller board over HDMI or other interfaces for video, or do you want eDP or LVDS - you can do USB for mouse and keyboard but how do you want to connect it). Physical design like hinges. You could buy a keyboard PCB, or strip down an existing one, or order say, a thinkpad laptop keyboard, work out its pin out and set it up.

So, literally *break it up*, *get familiar* with sites like hardware recs and superuser *then* you might be able to get answers to more focused questions as you go along.

I'd actually consider existing resources like hackaday to be a better starting point than Stack Exchange until you're sure about the details of your project.

Answer (score 1):

> and recommendations for what to buy

Hardware Recommendations might allow some questions you'd need to ask, but *very carefully* read what is on topic there, as they have very specific rules and what they will help with:
https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

And from [a meta post](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality/206#206) (linked in the above linked page):

> A question on Hardware Recommendations has one of two goals:
>
> ```
> A request for a product recommendation, OR
> A request for information that will lead to a product decision
> ```
>
> Hardware Recommendations is not here to:
>
> ```
> Provide technical support of hardware
> Provide step-by-step instructions for Do-It-Yourself installation
> ```
>
> Questions that ask for more than one piece of hardware at a time tend
>   to get closed because they're too broad for the community experts to
>   answer in one go

So you're going to have to research a bit first as to what hardware you need for your build, and then stick to specific questions. E.g. ask if a certain piece of hardware will work with another, etc.

Maybe asking in their chat rooms will give some advice on DIY build guides etc.